# Centos postfix issue

Tags: centos, postfix

I'm having issues with mail not being sent from our Centos server.

I have a number of domains on this VPS, for example:

domain1.com - website hosting only, mail is served by an external exchange server
domain2.com - full hosting, mail is set up as forwarding to external domains

If I enable the following in my main.cf:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
```

I can send email to my domain2.com email addresses which then forward to the relevant recipients defined by the forwarding setting in Plesk. With these settings in place it wont allow email to domain1.com out of the server.

If I comment out the lines in my main.cf file, mail to domain1.com works but the domain2.com email no longer works and I get a `Relay access denied> #SMTP#` message.

I understand I need to add my domain that has an external email exchange somewhere in the settings so my server sends the email externally for domain1.com (and the virtual mailboxes remain in place) but I'm a little lost as to where I put that setting.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not edit main.cf manually when using Plesk. If you have the mailservice for domain1.com enabled in Plesk, domain1.com is a virtual mailbox domain, therefore mail will be delivered locally. To get this fixed, disable mail service in Plesk for domain1.com. This will cause domain1.com to get removed from the Postfix virtual domains and mail will be delivered to the MX specified in your DNS records.